# Can android emulator play RTSP streams?

Tags: android, android-emulator, rtsp

I have tried a few sample RTSP streams on 3 different Android emulators (including one Intel image) without success.  These streams do work on a physical Android device.

Do Android emulators play RTSP stream at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried a few sample RTSP streams on many different Android emulators without success.so, Android Emulator Can't Play RTSP streams.